need sample logs for Jetty, i cant find in any of the docs
i need sample logs for jetty logAccess, Error, Request, WebSocket and Jetty System. I I can find any sample logs in the documentation and any AI gives constructed logs which may or may not be correct. Is there a best place to get sample logs? Thanks
I tried in different AI models, official documentation and github

Hi @aston-martin! It would be helpful to people reading this quesion, if you provide more details about your problem and the investigation that you have already done, links to places you have already checked.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
